# A request for an example of a band limited signal.

Tags: signal-processing

Recall that a signal $x(t)$ is **band-limited signal** if its Fourier transform
$$
X_{\Phi}(\Omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\Omega t}dt
$$
vanishes outside an interval, say $[-\Omega_0,\Omega_0]$. The problem is that I can not find **any** examples for such signals ! Even "simple" example such as
$$
x(t)=
\begin{cases}
1 & t\in[0,T]\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
is not band-limited signal. I would appreciate it if someone could write me examples of such signals

Comment: Interestingly, a signal cannot be both band-limited and time-limited. Your simple example can't work because it is zero outside of $[0,T]$.

Comment: One classic (and particularly important) example of a band-limited signal is the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).